# Why TensorFlow do not support strides = [1,0] or [0,1] for conv2d?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

It will mean the kernel moves on only one direction.

I want to let the kernel moves on the text sequence.

Are there alternative way to do it?

Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

batch_size = 2
sequence_len = 5
hidden_size = 16
kernel_len = 2
in_channel = 1
out_channel = hidden_size
a1 = np.array(np.arange(1, 1 + sequence_len * hidden_size).reshape([sequence_len, hidden_size, in_channel]),
              dtype=np.float32)

inputX = np.stack([a1, a1], axis=0)

kernel = np.array(np.arange(1, 1 + kernel_len * hidden_size * in_channel * out_channel), dtype=np.float32).reshape(
    [kernel_len, hidden_size, in_channel, out_channel])

conv2d = tf.nn.conv2d(inputX, kernel, strides=[1,0], padding='VALID')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    print(sess.run(tf.shape(conv2d)))
    print(sess.run(conv2d))
```

Comment: it's not clear what you need. could you elaborate?

Comment: I add the code. @thushv89

Answer (score 0):

We knows the principle of convolution:[image]

The scale formula can be written as :[image]
2D array(W1,W2) across kernel(ks1,ks2) with Stride(S1,S2) and Padding(P1,P2)

And it seems that you want the kernel move to the other character, it means the array after convolution either row or column should be 1, so the number inside floor should less than 1.

There is two way to reach the goal. We assume the original array is 10*20.

1. Set the kernel map as large as your column. ex:(10*3)
2. Set the Stride larger. If S>(W+2pad-ks), the formula will equal to 1.

In your case, just need to change:

```
kernel = np.array(np.arange(1, 1 + (kernel_len-1) * hidden_size * in_channel *out_channel),
    dtype=np.float32).reshape([kernel_len-1, hidden_size, in_channel, out_channel])
```

tf.shape(a1) is (5,16,1)

tf.shape(kernel) is (2,16,1,16)

According to the formula, you got [2,floor(5-2)+1,floor(16-16)+1,16] (stride=1) = [2,4,1,16]

when the kernel change to (1,16,1,16) the convolution array will be [2,5,1,16]

Comment: Your input shape is (2,5,16,1), but the kernel shape is (2,16,1,16). It doesn't match.

Comment: Thank you, but it can run. @CodingPeter

Comment: The output shape is (2,4,1,16), which shape you expect to get?

Comment: (2,5,1,16) is better. :) @CodingPeter

Comment: I have changed the answer, it give me an (2,5,1,16) array. Try again.

Comment: Thank you. In fact I need the (2,16) or (3,16) or (4,16) not (1,16).

Comment: kernel = np.array(np.arange(1, 1 + (kernel_len-1) * (hidden_size-1) * in_channel * out_channel), dtype=np.float32).reshape(
    [kernel_len-1, hidden_size-1, in_channel, out_channel])

you can change the parameter by youself